# Is $R[0,1]$ a Hausdorff space?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let's call $(R[0,1],\|.\|_1)$ the space of all Riemann integrable functions from $[0,1]$ to $\Bbb R$. Is it a Hausdorff space?

Also i need this (i think,intuitively) in order to prove that if $\|f_n-f\|_1\to 0$ and $|g_n-g\|_1\to 0$ then $\|f_ng_n-fg\|_1\to 0$.

Comment: W.r.t. which topology?

Comment: @kahen, the topology produced of the norm $\|.\|_1$.

Comment: Normed spaces are Hausdorff. If it's not a Hausdorff space, then it's not a norm.

Comment: Any metric space is $T_5$ hence Hausdroff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that, Riemann integrable functions is always bounded,  and then

$||f_{n}g_{n}-fg||_{1}= ||f_{n}g_{n}-f_{n}g + f_{n}g - fg||\leq ||f_{n}g_{n}-f_{n}g||_{1}+||f_{n}g-fg||_{1};$
and notice that, $||f_{n}g_{n}-f_{n}g||_{1}=\int_{0}^{1}|f_{n}(x) (g_{n}(x)-g(x))| dx \leq M ||g_{n}-g||_{1} \to 0$ as  $n\to \infty$; similarly, for the 
next term, and so $||f_{n}g_{n}-f_{n}g||_{1}\to 0$ as $n\to \infty.$

Answer (score 4):

Hint: let $f$ be the zero function and let $g$ be the function which is $1$ at $0$ and otherwise $0$.  What can you say about open sets containing $f$ and $g$?